# How to plot histogram in R?

Tags: r, histogram

I  am using R and I would like to plot a histogram where `x-axis` is the number of vehicles and `y-axis` is the time interval. 
Something like:

[image: this]

Comment: Please check the [R documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/hist.html) before posting here. If you get stuck somewhere, please give details on what you've tried and what error messages you get.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I guess you need a barplot:

```
x <- data.frame(n_vehicles = c(10, 20, 30, 40),
                time_interval = c(2, 5, 4, 9))
barplot(height = x$time_interval,
        names.arg = x$n_vehicles)
```

[image]

Or alternatively:

```
plot(x = x$n_vehicles,
     y = x$time_interval,
     type = "h")
```

The `"h"` stands for "histogram".

Comment: I create two histograms x and y using the above code. How can I plot them in the same plot?