# Create histogram from summarized data R

Tags: r, histogram, data-analysis

How could I create a histogram from this set of summarized data in R?

[image]

I attempted this:

```
dataset <- c(4,17,12,6)
hist(dataset)
```

However, this showed me the data without the "0-19","60-99" breaks etc.

I would like to know how to create this histogram with the correct breaks and names. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have these 4 numbers in R already?  `barplot(c("0-19"=4,"20-39"=17,"40-59"=12,"60-99"=6))` will take you quite far but one can do better.  Note that from R-s perspective this is barplot, not histogram.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to plot histogram in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38480183/how-to-plot-histogram-in-r)

Comment: Perhaps a better duplicate is [How can I create a histogram from aggregated data in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9133057/how-can-i-create-a-histogram-from-aggregated-data-in-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a barplot.

```
Height = c(4,17,12,6)
Bins = c("0-19", "20-39", "40-59", "60-99")
barplot(Height, names.arg=Bins)
```

[image: Barplot]

`barplot` has many parameters that you might consider adjusting to make this prettier.

Comment: The question wants a histogram not a bar plot; this can be achieved using `PreBinnedHistogram` from the `HistogramTools` package, for example. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/21950736/1895415